# zeppelin hive interpreter throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hive, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I have deployed zeppelin 0.6 and configured hive under Jdbc interpreter.

Tried executing

```
%hive     
show databases
```

Throws:

> org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getConnection(JDBCInterpreter.java:220)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getStatement(JDBCInterpreter.java:233)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:292)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:398)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:383)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212092/classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hive-jdbc-hivedriver

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this issue this morning.  I'm not sure if this is the recommended way to fix, but I downloaded the binary packages for Hive 1.2, and Hadoop 2.6.4.  I then copied the following jars to `./interpreter/jdbc/` and reloaded zeppelin `./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh reload`

`cp ~/Dev/Hadoop/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar ./interpreter/jdbc/`

`cp ~/Dev/Hadoop/hadoop-2.6.4/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar ./interpreter/jdbc/`

Comment: @Cooper
Thanks a lot, worked for me as well. As you mentioned, is there a better way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

1)
You could download just Hive JDBC driver instead of whole Hive jars set, for example, one from Cloudera:

http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-5-17.html

2)

Hive starting with 0.14 will have a standalone jar for JDBC part:

> hive-jdbc-standalone.jar

but until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9600 is resolved,
you would need two more jars:

> hadoop-common.jar
>
> hadoop-auth.jar

to put into classpath along with hive-jdbc-standalone.jar

Answer (score 0):

The top rated answer given here fixes the issue

However I have added the classpath of HADOOP_HOME to interpreter.sh to take the jar files in common

Below is the line which I have added to bin/interpreter.sh inside zeppelin

```
HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/
addJarInDirForIntp "${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common
```

Comment: @Cooper6581 I am getting similar error but  ```  ERROR [2019-01-23 07:54:59,512] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:141)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)
````
Any idea how to fix