# How to add a jar in zeppelin?

Tags: json, jar, hive, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

How to add a jar in Zeppelin for %hive interpreter?

I have tried

```
%z.dep('');
add jar <jar path>
```

Also [zeppelin hive interpreter throws ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713358/zeppelin-hive-interpreter-throws-classnotfoundexception/38726719#38726719)

Adding to  `./interpreter/hive/` throughs thrift exception while `add jar` says file not found.

How to do it? I am trying to add jsonserde.jar by Amazon to parse DynamoDB imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the version 0.5.6 for me the following worked:

```
%hive
add jar /home/hadoop/jsonserde.jar
```

Comment: no, it is not working because I am not using hive
`org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: paragraph_1510199763504_1388344895's Interpreter %hiv not found`

Answer (score 8):

The recommended way is using Zeppelin's [Dependency Management](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/manual/dependencymanagement.html)

It can add jar file or maven artifact.

the dependency jar will be downloaded to local-repo.

> NOTE: If the jar file is compiled from source, when you compile again, it will NOT be synchronised automatically(download again). You need go to `interpreter` setting, click edit and OK will trigger another download to local-repo.

---

> NOTE: If you use one scala version first, and compiled again with another version. It will report `Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror`. remove already downloaded jar with `rm -rf local-repo/*`

---

> NOTE: z.dep is deprecated.

Comment: This is cool! 1. What is the property name to add a jar which is stored locally on the host 2. What will the relative path from root or from Zeppelin install directory?

Comment: I just simply use absolute path.

Comment: What is the property name that you used?

Comment: It is NOT in `Properties` part. it is in `Dependencies` part

Comment: I do not have that segment. Possibly the zeppelin version is old.

Comment: This method is annoying because there is absolutely no way to automate it. The nice thing about using the %dep was that you could use the notebook API to load the jar

Answer (score 4):

### Updated on Zeppelin 0.8.x

You can now load external dependencies or jars using  `%dep` or `%spark.dep` (if using Spark). Documentation is on zeppline website:  [Dynamic Dependency Loading](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#3-dynamic-dependency-loading-via-sparkdep-interpreter)

```scala
%dep z.load("/path/to/your/packages.jar")
```

or

```scala
%spark.dep
z.reset() // clean up previously added artifact and repository

// add maven repository
z.addRepo("RepoName").url("RepoURL")

// add maven snapshot repository
z.addRepo("RepoName").url("RepoURL").snapshot()

// add credentials for private maven repository
z.addRepo("RepoName").url("RepoURL").username("username").password("password")
```

Answer (score 2):

Example, tested in Zeppelin 0.8.1:

```
%dep
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.addRepo("OSS SNAPSHOTS").url("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
z.load("org.zouzias:spark-lucenerdd_2.11:0.3.7")
```