# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver With java hive jdbc connection

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to use the Hive driver in my java class to query my hdfs, but I've have hit a wall.

I have dredged through numerous questions related to this issue but none of them have remedied this problem. I know its something to do with classpath, but the configuration in my POM file should add the hive driver to it, right?

Im using `mvn package` to build it, if there're any suggestions i'll be very grateful! NOTE: I need to compile using jdk 1.7

in main class:

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
```

POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-count-records</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212092/classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hive-jdbc-hivedriver)

Comment: Not clear how you're running this code... Note: Your JDBC driver needs to match the Hive server version